# AWS S3 scaling connections horizontally

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Suppose you have to implement video streaming platform from scratch. It doesn't matter where you gonna store metadata, your not-very-popular video files will be stored at file system, or object store in case you want to use Cloud. If you'll choose AWS, in order to boost AWS S3 read performance, you can make multiple read requests against the same video file, see [Performance Guidelines for Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance-guidelines.html):

> You can use concurrent connections to Amazon S3 to fetch different
>   byte ranges from within the same object. This helps you achieve higher
>   aggregate throughput versus a single whole-object request.

In the same time, as you know, disk I/O is sequential for all HDD/SDD drives, so to boost read performance (if neglect RAM necessary for uncompress/decrypt each video chunk) you have to read from multiple disks (YouTube use RAID).

*Why S3 will have better performance on concurrent byte range requests agains the same file? Isn't it stored on single disk? I suppose S3 may have some replication factor and still store the file on multiple disks, does it?*

Comment: It depends on which storage class you choose. S3 redundantly stores objects on multiple devices across a minimum of three AZs in an S3 region for Standard, Standard-IA, and Glacier. Also be aware of CloudFront CDN options for delivering your video content.

Comment: @jarmod thanks! but 3 AZs explain throughput increase only for ~3 reading threads.

Comment: Also worth visiting https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/AmazonS3BestPractices.pdf and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHeTn9pHNKo&t=3106s.